# gunicorn systemd service not starting - Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC

Tags: python, linux, nginx, flask, gunicorn

Environment: CentOS8 with NGINX, gunicorn and flask

While practicing in lab, i have created a flask app and able to start it using gunicorn with below command

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi
```

Then i created a systemd service.

systemd.service config:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=abk
Group=abk
WorkingDirectory=/home/abk/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/abk/myproject/myprojectenv/bin" 

ExecStart=/home/abk/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3
--bind unix:/home/abk/myproject/myproject.sock -u abk -g abk wsgi

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Status of service is showing failure and journalctl is showing below error

```
Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
```

I followed many suggestions from tech community and nothing seems to work.

I have done chown on gunicorn file for abk user. Still issue persists.

If i try below command it works,

```
/home/abk/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 -u abk -g abk wsgi
```

[image]

```
[abk@centos01 myproject]$ /home/abk/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/abk/myproject/myproject.sock -u abk -g abk wsgi
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2736] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2736] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/abk/myproject/myproject.sock (2736)
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2736] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2739] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2739
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2740] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2740
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2742] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2742
```

but i am not able to configure it as service.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe caused by unix socket. Try this again, and we will find it.
`/home/abk/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/abk/myproject/myproject.sock -u abk -g abk wsgi`

Comment: [abk@centos01 myproject]$ /home/abk/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/abk/myproject/myproject.sock -u abk -g abk wsgi
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2736] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2736] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/abk/myproject/myproject.sock (2736)
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2736] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2739] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2739
[2020-09-25 18:31:06 +0800] [2740] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2740